# c# enum names to filter on in a DropDownList instead of value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have a list of enums that includes a enumeration called Default.

```
public enum Fruits { Default = Banana, 
                    Banana = 1, 
                    Orange = 2, 
                    Grapefruit = 3 }
```

I need to populate a dropdownlist that excludes the Default field.

```
Html.DropDownList("fruitSelector", 
                Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fruits)).Cast<Fruits>()
                    .OrderBy(o => o.GetDescription())
                    .Where(o => o != Fruits.Default)
                    .Select(o => new SelectListItem() {Text = o.GetDescription(), Value = ((int) o).ToString()}), "-- All Fruits --",
                new {@class = "form-control", @aria_describedby="sizing-addon1"})
```

when i try to filter on Fruits.Default it removes BOTH default and the Banana.  How can i do a filter comparison where i only remove Default?

[[CORRECTION]] this enum duplicates my problem.  I honestly don't understand the difference.

```
public enum Fruits
    {
        Default = Peaches,
        Peaches = 1,
        Bananas = 2,
        Grapefruit = 3,
        Apple = 101,
        Watermellon = 102
    }
```

or

```
public enum Fruits2
{
    Default = Mangos,
    Mangos = 1,
    Dates = 2,
    Figs = 3,
    Apples = 101,
    Limes = 102,
    Grapes = 103
}
```

Comment: Does the above code compile? Or do you have an extension method not shown here? Otherwise how would `o.GetDescription()` compile without errors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467519/about-enum-and-dataannotation

Comment: @Sach ya that is a method to get custom Description annotation.  you can exclude that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible *as it is*. The problem is your Enum structure.

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Default = Peaches,
    Peaches = 1,
    Bananas = 2,
    Grapefruit = 3,
    Apple = 101,
    Watermellon = 102
}
```

You're saying value of `Default` is `Peaches` of which value in turn is `1`. Which essentially is the same as (`B` is `Peaches` and `A` is `Default`:

```
int B = 1;
int A = B;
```

So when we use `Enum.Parse()`, it treats both the same, and picks the first value. You'll understand when you look at the following scenario. Run the following code, with your current Enum:

```
var deflt = Enum.Parse(typeof(Fruits), Fruits.Default.ToString());
var peach = Enum.Parse(typeof(Fruits), Fruits.Peaches.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(deflt);
Console.WriteLine(peach);
```

The output is going to be:

> Default
>
> Default

Then change your Enum to this:

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Peaches = Default ,
    Default = 1,
    Bananas = 2,
    Grapefruit = 3,
    Apple = 101,
    Watermellon = 102
}
```

And run the above two lines of code again. Your output this time will be:

> Peaches
>
> Peaches

That is, `Parse()` picks the first defined Enum when there's an equality like you have.

**EDIT:**

The above explanation is slightly incorrect, as pointed out in the comments below by George Alexandria. Please see his explanation:
***You have the different output when use Peaches = Default , Default = 1, and Default = Peaches, Peaches = 1, because you invoke Enum.ToString in Console.WriteLine. If you look at the var deflt, var peach you will see that they are the same in the both cases and they are the value which name is the first by alphabetical.***

---

But there is a workaround. From your initial code sample what I gather is you need a list of Enums, their descriptions, and their numerical values, am I correct? So, I would first just grab a list of *strings* excluding `Default` which is quite simple. Then iterate through the string list, and add to a list of your `SelectListItem` class objects.

```
var res = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits))
    .Where(x => x != "Default");

List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (string fruit in res)
{
    string desc = EnumHelper<Fruits>.GetEnumDescription(fruit); // This is a utility method I use. You can get the description using your extension method.
    int val = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Fruits), fruit);
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { enumName = fruit, enumDesc = desc, enumVal = val });
}
```

And if you *must* have that `OrderBy`, after creating your `SelectListItem` list, sort it once again by `Description`.

Comment: You have the different output when use `Peaches = Default , Default = 1,` and `Default = Peaches, Peaches = 1,` because you invoke `Enum.ToString` in `Console.WriteLine`. If you look at the `var deflt, var peach` you will see that they are the same in the both cases and they are the value which **name is the first by alphabetical**

Comment: That is interesting to know! Thanks! I'll update my answer with this information.

Comment: the enum is already in use and cannot be changed.  plus it doesn't make much sense to change the enums that way.. the reason that default is used i believe in the existing code is to have an easy way to change the default if need be. but the value of the existing values cannot change.  so making peach = default, is a big diff than saying default = peach.   So there is no way to get this done other than with your workaround?  hmm

Comment: @Sach how do i get the extension method working in place of what you wrote for getting a description.  meaning, there is no enum the way you did it, so how can the extension description i have available be used.   referring to this line: string desc = EnumHelper<Fruits>.GetEnumDescription(fruit);

Comment: I assumed you have your own extension method, which is what you said in response to one of my earlier comment. I'm not sure about extension methods, but you're welcome to use the [utility method I usually use](https://gist.github.com/sachintha81/82f3d6b5974e4b35b650cff4e2179e90), which I obtained originally from a SO answer as well.

Comment: yes it is an extension method.  but it extends a enum type.  i just don't know how to fit it into your solution.  before i was doing it in the predicate that took a enum type. but what you have there is a string that you are working with.

Comment: You don't really _need_ an extension method. Just call the utility method I've provided like this: `string desc = EnumHelper<Fruits>.GetEnumDescription(fruit);`

Comment: still having some trouble getting it into the dropdownlist.  Is there an alternate approach to maybe Add an Attribute annotation to the Enum so that it can be EXCLUED from the Selection?  Seems like that would be a better way.

Comment: What problem do you have? Because this code, eventually, does exactly what you were doing in the first place anyway, since it creates a list of objects of `SelectListItem`.

Comment: i tried your solution, and i still get default in the list.

Comment: @user1161137 that simply is not possible. Here's the _entire_ code I ran and it produces the expected results just fine. https://dotnetfiddle.net/GFcklC

Comment: yes, i see your example working... overall this process seems very flaky, cause as soon as you even move the enums around (position in list)  or introduce additional enums (with unique values)   it breaks.  I will add another fruit enum to the description... to prove my point... yet your solution should work, cause it's just about getting rid of the default enum, but it doesn't.

Comment: don't understand... just looked at your sample and i see default in the output list.  tx for your help btw.. i know this is taking your time.

Comment: i see you removed your comment showing the second sample... so i presume you confirmed that it wasn't working too.

Comment: Yes it doesn't work for some and does for others. And I figured the real problem is the equality in your enum, and it messed up when the `Parse()` method is used. May I ask why you want that equality? You'd be better off if you use a clean enum.

Comment: for convenience in code where at the present time when code gets hit that that particular value is used.. because in the future, another value could be used as the 'default'  and you don't want to have to go through all the locations in the code to update what new default value should be.  it used in a lot of places that way.

Comment: ok, it seems to work if you replace your line of .Where(x => x != Fruits.Default.ToString());   with  temp = "Default";
            var res = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits));
            res = res.Where(e => e != temp).ToArray();     rather than getting the default key from the enum, we already know it's the default we want removed, so explicitly putting that into a string ensures we're dealing with the correct named enum... then the rest of your code works.

Comment: @Sach update your answer to a literal string 'Default'  rather than depending on Fruits.Default.ToString()   ... and i'll accept the answer.

Comment: Done. But I still do think your enum structure is vulnerable to a lot of unintended consequence, and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: also.. you should add that Enum Helper to the answer in case someone else needs this.  no guarantees that that part will be available in the future if not part of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare enum values by their names, because `Default` and `Banana` are equal. So just try to retrieve names, filter them and parse them to values.

```
var res = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits))
              .Where(o => o != nameof(Fruits.Default))
              .Select(o => Enum.Parse(typeof(Fruits), o))
              .Cast<Fruits>().ToList();
```

It's your full example:

```
Html.DropDownList("fruitSelector",
            Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits))
                .Where(o => o != nameof(Fruits.Default))
                .Select(o => Enum.Parse(typeof(Fruits), o)).Cast<Fruits>()
                .OrderBy(o => o.GetDescription())
                .Select(o => new SelectListItem() { Text = o.GetDescription(), Value = ((int)o).ToString() }), "-- All Fruits --",
            new { @class = "form-control", @aria_describedby = "sizing-addon1" })
```

Comment: that seems to work on the first enum that i put in... but i noticed that that enum wasn't replicating my problem... i added the second enum which is slightly different... but breaks your solution.  i honestly don't understand why.  tx for your help

Comment: this solution gives, apple, bananas, grapefruit, default, watermellon... so peaches doesn't show up but default does.

Comment: @user1161137 You first enum works because `Banane` **lesser by alphabetical** that `Default`, but `Peaches` greater that `Default`, so when you try to Parse the `1`, Parse returns the **lesser value by name**. For the second enum it's `Default`

Comment: @user1161137 If you are looking the solution for the second enum you can try a workaround in the **_Sach_** answer.

Comment: Yes, the second enum is what i'm dealing with.. i just didn't translate the problem correctly to stack. I'm not dealing with fruits :-)